# Problems using get_the_terms in a plugin

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm attemting to craft a small plugin to get_the_terms from a custom taxonomy for a custom post type. The code below is causing a critical error, but I'm in the dark on why.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
 
define('ANTLS_PLUGIN_DIR_URL',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) );

add_shortcode( 'post_terms_list', 'antls_post_terms_list' );

function antls_post_terms_list( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'name' => 'category',
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'exclude' => '',
        'include' => '',
        'order' => 'ASC',   
    ), $atts);

    global $post;

    $terms = get_the_terms( array(
        'post_id' => $post->ID,
        'taxonomy' => $atts['name'],
        'hide_empty' => $atts['hide_empty'],
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => $atts['order'],
        'parent'   => 0
    ) );

    $html .= '<ul class="antls tax-list-'.$atts['name'].'">';

    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            
            if( !empty( $atts['exclude'] ) ) {
                $exclude = explode( ',',$atts['exclude'] );
               if( in_array( $term->term_id, $exclude) ) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            
            if( !empty( $atts['include'] ) ) {
                $include = explode( ',',$atts['include'] );
                if( !in_array( $term->term_id, $include) ) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
                
            $html .= '<li class="tax-item-'.$atts['name'].'" data-taxname="'.strtolower( $term->name ).'">';
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

            $html .= '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';      
            
            $html .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: get_the_terms recieves 2 parameters - post object/post id and taxonomy name) What error do you get?

Comment: @anton 'there has been a critical error on this website'

Comment: check your sites PHP error log, the critical error message is just a generic something went wrong screen so that visitors don't see the actual error message or private data. Otherwise anton is correct, you gave `get_the_terms` an array of options, but the documentation says it needs completely different parameters. Did this used to be a different function? Say `get_terms`? See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

Comment: I usually preffer `wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'taxonomy', $args)`, I know it calls get_terms() inside, but here is more easy to set post id.